# How to import module up multiple levels from base?

Tags: pytest

I'm trying to call a module several levels up from pytest run directory.  How do I import this module?

I've tried:

```
sys.path.insert(0, 'path/to/module')
import modulename
```

Here's the directory structure:

```
tools
  common
    modulename.py (contains class A)
  functional_test (this is where I'm running pytest; tools/functional_test)
    conftest.py
    pytest.ini
    tests
      typea (this is tools/funtional_tests/tests/typea)
        tests_typea1.py

Under tests_typea1.py, I want to import class A from modulename.py under tools/common.
```

Getting the following Errors:

```
ImportError
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'modulename'
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, after having another person look over my code, I realized that I miss-spelled my the import .  Ugh...  Note to self: change font style and confirm spelling. :).  The above `sys.path.insert` or `sys.path.append` with `import <modulename>` works.